# Use output of command-line operator to create a file

Tags: batch-file

I would like to use output of the command

```
wmic cpu get name
```

that returns

```
Name
Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-3240 CPU @ 3.40GHz
```

to create a filename.

So filename should be like

```
i3-3240.txt
```

Is it possible todo with script of BAT file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this from the command line you can use:

```
for /f "tokens=3 delims= " %i in ('wmic cpu get name') do if not "%i"=="" type nul>%i.txt
```

Or from a batch file:

```
for /f "tokens=3 delims= " %%i in ('wmic cpu get name') do if not "%%i"=="" type nul>%%i.txt
```

Or alternatively:

```
for /f "skip=1 tokens=3 delims= " %i in ('wmic cpu get name') do type nul>%i.txt
```

and

```
for /f "skip=1 tokens=3 delims= " %%i in ('wmic cpu get name') do type nul>%%i.txt
```